# listview dynamic items height

Tags: android, listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:background="@drawable/round_shape"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="25">
    <TextView
        android:text="Title"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/borrowBookTitle"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        />
    <TextView
        android:text="Locate"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/locate"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#838383"
        />
    <TextView
        android:text="borrowStartDate"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"`enter code here`
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/borrowStartDate"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@color/childview_background"
    />
    <TextView
        android:text="borrowEndDate"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/borrowEndDate"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@color/childview_background"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="75">

    <TextView
        android:text="D-11"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/borrowDday"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/button1"
        android:id="@+id/renewBtn"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="RENEW"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Above xml files is `Listview's` item xml file.
`borrowStartDate`, `borrowEndDate` and `renewBtn` visiblility is gone.
But When click on item, change gone to visible

```
borrowListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                        TextView startDate = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.borrowStartDate);
                        TextView endDate = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.borrowEndDate);
                        Button renewBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.renewBtn);
                        if ( startDate.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                            startDate.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(view.getContext(), R.anim.slide_down_and_fade_in));
                            endDate.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(view.getContext(), R.anim.slide_down_and_fade_in));
                            renewBtn.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(view.getContext(), R.anim.fade_in));

                            startDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            endDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            renewBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        else {
                            startDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            endDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            renewBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

It's change visibility code

Problem is `Listview` height matched **When Items Gone**'s height.
So When I clicked each item not directly showing under parts.

I want to When click on items, `Listview` height automatically expand

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
        <WebView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/rightWebView"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Refresh"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/button1"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/refresh_picto"
            android:id="@+id/refreshBorrowBook"
            android:onClick="refreshBorrow"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/borrowBookList"
            android:dividerHeight="10dp"
            android:divider="@color/main_background"
            />
        <TextView
            android:text="예약 목록"
            android:paddingStart="50dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_shape"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/childview_background"
            android:id="@+id/reservation_list_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/reservationBookList"
            android:dividerHeight="10dp"
            android:divider="@color/main_background"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is fragments code

---

Add snapshots

[after refresh button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFl5s.png) after click refresh button

[when click item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrOzL.png) when click item

If scrolling down, then showing listview's other parts

I don't want to scrolling.

Just When click items then listview get heights automaticially.

I think this problem is not relative with `notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: After change visibility call `notifyDataSetChanged();` It will works.

Comment: Your question is not clear ..pls add some snapshots

Comment: show how it looks, and how you want it to look. It is not clear without visual.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
view.getLayoutParams().Height=value
```

You don't have to toggle visibility by the way
Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Below method calculate each Child View height , You must call below method after pressing button of any child view  in Listview to visible and invisible.

```
public class Utility {
        public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
            ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
            if (listAdapter == null) {
                // pre-condition
                return;
            }

            int totalHeight = 0;
            int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
                listItem.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
            }

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
            listView.setLayoutParams(params);
            listView.requestLayout();
        }
    }
```

Call this function right after you change ListView items, like that:

```
Utility.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(myListView);
```

Comment: I added your code end of  `borrowListView.setOnItemClickListener()` But still not just showing all child views, occur scrolling , when `textview`s' gone to visible